# Grouping files in zsh

Tags: zsh

I have 104 files that need to be concatenated in groups of 10. The last group would be 4 files. Order of concatenation is important.

I was planning to sort the files (standard name sort works) and then pipe into a concatenation command in groups of 10, but I'd like to do it in zsh.

I can get the first 10 files in zsh with:

```
cat *([1,10]) > newfile1
```

How can I get the next 10 into newfile2, then the next....

I often have a need for this task, so I'm trying to stay generic. Is there an easy way to create this loop in zsh?

I am new to zsh and would very much appreciate explaining any suggestion.

Thank you!

Comment: You need a loop; `cat` alone doesn't know how to group its arguments into distinct subsets intended for multiple output files.

Comment: [`split`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html) will do most of the work if you have it.

Comment: I would create an array containing the names of all files and then loop over the array in increments of 10.

Comment: _Is there an easy way to create this loop_  : zsh has arithmetic (i.e. counting) loops. This is explained in the _zshmisc_ man page, section _COMPLEX COMMANDS_.